# Unbiased Render Engine on Android?

Tags: android, rendering, render, renderer

Is there any open-source unbiased Render Engine that would compile and run on Android ?

I'm not talking about Game Engines or "3D OpenGl Engines" but about Path-Tracer Renderer such as Yafaray, LuxRender, Sunflow, etc...

My android app is able to generate a set of 3D data (representing geometry) and I'd like to render it with a Photo-Realistic Render Engine such as the ones mentioned above (of course this would require to write an exporter from my app to the render Engine but that's not a problem.)

Comment: Messing with the source code of [android version of blender](http://download.blender.org/demo/android/) could be usefull.